# How to embed a new .resx (resources) file to an application

Tags: c#, .net, compilation, resources, exe

I'm building an application that has two forms,
one form where you put information encrypts that type of information and then decrypts it into a new resources file used in the second form.
My goal is to use the first form to compile and generate an executable file of the second form
but I don't know how to do that.
and my second problem is that I don't know how to embed that new resources file into the generated executable file.
Can anyone help me or give me some guidance on what to use exactly, how to compile an executable file of one form and embed that new resources (.resx) file into it.

Comment: Figure out how you want to compile your code at run-time, and than resource embedding would be quite obvious. It is unclear where you stuck exactly, so please [edit] the question to ask *one* concrete question.

Comment: I'm stuck in compiling, I don't know how to compile form2 using form1, and I want to embed a resource file to the compiled form2 executable